# How to change the opacity of the material Claraplayer Js

Tags: javascript, three.js, clara.io

I am trying to control the opacity of the material

using this command

```
//To get exiting value
api.scene.get({id:'a8c6435c-f4ff-4e06-b41e-dac33474f856', plug:'Material', property:'opacity'});

//To set new value
api.scene.set({id:'a8c6435c-f4ff-4e06-b41e-dac33474f856', plug:'Material', property:'opacity'}, 0.3)
```

But its not working.

This is the reference I am following.
https://clara.io/docs/tutorial-demo-SetMaterialProps.html

Comment: Shouldn't the `transparent` property be set to `true`, if you're using `opacity`?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

```
api.scene.set({id:'a8c6435c-f4ff-4e06-b41e-dac33474f856', plug:'Material', property:'opacityFactor'}, '0.3')
```

The property name is: `opacityFactor`